# Python- how to convert Datetimefield from model into UTC time zone

Tags: python

For python, how do i convert a DatetimeField (has my local server time) to a datetimefield in UTC zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best that I can come up with is to convert it to a timestamp and then use the `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` class method

```
import time
import datetime

def to_utc(dateTime)
    timeStamp = time.mktime(dateTime.timetuple()) + dateTime.microsecond
    return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timeStamp)
```

Comment: @David Hsu: If an answer is accepted, it is presumably useful also. You can - and if the answer warrants - accept **and** vote it as useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Minsk'))
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 8, 15, 32, 7, 816893, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Minsk' EEST+3:00:00 DST>)
>>> x = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> x
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 8, 15, 32, 26, 960839)
>>> x.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Minsk'))
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 8, 15, 32, 26, 960839, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Minsk' MMT+1:50:00 STD>)
>>> x.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Minsk')).isoformat()
'2011-08-08T15:32:26.960839+01:50'
>>> datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Minsk')).isoformat()
'2011-08-08T15:33:16.720865+03:00'
```

Compare plz :) replace is not a good idea. The best is to convert to timestamp and then to datetime again.

Best idea:

> > > pytz.timezone('Europe/Minsk').localize(datetime.datetime.now())